# Select element with display none is empty string in $_REQUEST

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-select, display

I can't get the value of my textfield `new_list_id` using PHP. Here is my code:

```
<select id="mymenu" size="1" name='sf_old' class='short_tf'>
    <option >&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="nothing">New Input</option>
    <option value="101">101</option>
    <option value="102">102</option>
</select>

<input type='text' class='short_tf' name='new_sf' id='new_list_id' style='display:none;'/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
    selectmenu.onchange=function(){
    var index = selectmenu.selectedIndex;
    if (index == '1') {
        document.getElementById('new_list_id').style.display='inline';
        document.getElementById('mymenu').style.display='none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Using PHP I can get the value of my SELECT tag `mymenu` if it is the one selected but I can't retrieve the value of my textfield `new_list_id` if it is one present and the SELECT tag is hidden.

Problem: the value I get for my textfield is the string "nothing" which is from my SELECT tag. Can't figure out why.

I'm also using the name attribute but it gives me the same result. This is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sf_old'])) {
    $sf=$_REQUEST['sf_old'];
} elseif(isset($_REQUEST['new_sf'])) {
    $sf=$_REQUEST['new_sf'];
} else {
    $sf='';
}
            
echo $sf;
```

Comment: No PHP code in a PHP tagged question. The irony

Comment: @Alexander please check also my php code. sorry, i should have included it earlier.thanks

Comment: Yeah, you had a misunderstanding which you can check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `display` style property of the element to `none` will only make it *visually* hidden. It won't change the fact that it will or won't be sent to the server. So, the first condition is always true and the `else` clause if never triggered.

You can try an alternative way:

```
$sf = "";

if(isset($_POST['sf_old']) && isset($_POST['new_sf'])){
  if($_POST['sf_old'] == "nothing"){
    $sf = $_POST['new_sf'];
  } else {
    $sf = $_POST['sf_old'];
  }
}

echo $sf;
```

I prefer using directly `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for your explanation, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

From php you have to use the "name" attribute. "new_sf" the id attribute is for client side scripting mostly.

Comment: thanks for the response. i'm also using the "name" attribute but it gives me the same result. i always get the value "nothing" from the <select> tag.

Comment: @user1957878 even though the select tag is "hidden" the php code still sees it and its value, thats why you always get "nothing" which is the default value of the select option.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input type='text' class='short_tf' name='new_list_id' id='new_list_id' style='display:none;'/>
```

The `name` attribute is the one PHP will use to retrieve the value.

Comment: @scartag i'm also using the name attribute but it gives me the same value which is the string "nothing" even though i input new values for my textfield.

Comment: try receiving it as `$_POST['new_list_id']`

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming this: 
You want to get the value from the input field if it's not empty otherwise you want the value from the drop down.

you need to expand on you if statements a little

here is the whole code:

```
<?php 

$sf='';

if(isset($_REQUEST['sf_old'])){    
    $sf = $_REQUEST['sf_old'];
        if($sf == "nothing")
            if(isset($_REQUEST['new_sf'])){
                $sf = $_REQUEST['new_sf'];
        }

    }

    echo $sf;
    ?>
```